# Deg. in rotation

Tags: javascript, css

I am building time picker where you can set time on "real" clocks.
Im finding the position of mouse and degrees + rotating div using this script

```
var g;
        var h;
        if (e.target.id == "rotationSliderContainer") {

            g = e.offsetX;
            h = e.offsetY;
        } else {
            g = e.target.offsetLeft + e.offsetX;
            h = e.target.offsetTop + e.offsetY;
        }
        var atan = Math.atan2(g - radius, h - radius);
        deg = -atan / (Math.PI / 180) + 180;

        var presne = Math.abs(deg - (Math.round(deg / 30) * 30));

        if (presne <= 2) deg = Math.round(deg / 30) * 30;

        if(deg == 360)
                deg = 0;
        two.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
```

it works fine but it has little bug , whenever i want to move div , between 12 and 1,2,3 its flipping between 12 and one of those values.

Here is a live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/afo7ky03/1/ 
Is there any shortcut how to prevent this unwanted behavior or did i simply made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: For me, the bug happens when the mouse is too close to the center of the clock. If my mouse it on the outside of the clock, it works better (regardless of which number I am at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if/else condition is switching between events in the rotationSliderContainer and other DOM elements (such as the rotationSlider and the body).  That else condition is your culprit.

```
if (e.target.id == "rotationSliderContainer") {

        g = e.offsetX;
        h = e.offsetY;
    } else {
        g = e.target.offsetLeft + e.offsetX;
        h = e.target.offsetTop + e.offsetY;
    }
```

remove those two lines and it should be fine.

```
    if (e.target.id == "rotationSliderContainer") {

        g = e.offsetX;
        h = e.offsetY;
    }
```

Cool clock ^_^